# Change an XML layout when a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am trying to change the xml layout/contents of a linear layout inside of a scroll view when a button is pressed. I do not want to call a new Activity when the button is pressed or use setVisibility.

So far, 10% of the screen is reserved as a navigation bar housing 2 buttons. Below that is a scroll view with a linear layout inside, inside which will be content. I would like the content to change within the Linear Layout when the "next" button is pressed.
This is for a reference app designed to hold 50+ pages of information.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_weight="10">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPrevious"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Previous" 
            android:layout_weight="30"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="50"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Next" android:layout_weight="20"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="80">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="top|center"
                android:text="Header"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="According to the Oxford English Dictionary, hello is an alteration of hallo, hollo,[3] which came from Old High German &quot;halâ, holâ, emphatic imperative of halôn, holôn to fetch, used especially in hailing a ferryman.&quot;[4] It also connects the development of hello to the influence of an earlier form, holla, whose origin is in the French holà (roughly, 'whoa there!', from French là 'there').[5] As in addition to hello, hallo and hollo, hullo and (rarely) hillo also exist as variants or related words, the word can be spelt using any of all five vowels.Hello is alternatively thought to come from the word hallo (1840) via hollo (also holla, holloa, halloo, halloa).[9] The definition of hollo is to shout or an exclamation originally shouted in a hunt when the quarry was spotted:[9] Fowler's has it that &quot;hallo&quot; is first recorded &quot;as a shout to call attention&quot; in 1864.[16]" android:textSize="20dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:layout_weight="10">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TestAd"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what do you want the content to change to? You're not explaining things very well.

Comment: I was planning to change it to a picture and accompanying text, acting like a reference app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FragmentPager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say why you don't want to use `setVisivility()`, but my first recommendation would be to use a `FrameLayout` and set different views visible or invisible based on the button presses. Another thought is to use a [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html).